# Proving an inequality with a function that uses matrix inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $A$ be a matrix with all nonnegative entries and row sums strictly
less than one, let $v$ be a vector with all entries between zero
and one, and let $B\equiv\left(I-A\mathrm{diag}\left(v\right)\right)^{-1}$.
Finally, consider function $f:\mathbb{R}^{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
given by
$$
f(v)=v_{1}b_{11}+\sum_{k}\left(1-v_{k}\right)\frac{b_{1k}b_{k1}^{2}}{b_{11}}.
$$
I want to show that $f(v)\leq f(\iota)$, where $\iota$ is the vector
of all ones.

In the simple case in which $A$ is upper (lower) triangular then
$B$ is also upper (lower) triangular, and hence
$$
f(v)=\left[v_{1}+\left(1-v_{1}\right)b_{11}\right]b_{11},
$$
with
$
b_{11}=\frac{1}{1-a_{11}v_{1}}.
$
This implies that $f(v)\leq f(\iota)$ is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1-a_{11}v_{1}^{2}}{\left(1-a_{11}v_{1}\right)^{2}}\leq\frac{1}{1-a_{11}},
$$
which is equivalent to $a_{11}\left(1-v_{1}\right)^{2}\geq0$, which
is obviously true.

Extending this result beyond triangular matrices is difficult because
now $\sum_{k}\left(1-v_{k}\right)\frac{b_{1k}b_{k1}^{2}}{b_{11}}\neq\left(1-v_{1}\right)b_{11}^{2}$
and also the expressions for $b_{ij}$ are complicated. Since numerical
simulations show this result $f(v)\leq f(\iota)$ holds, I am hoping
there is some trick that I can apply for this proof. Perhaps I would
be using the set of equations in $B\left(I-A\mathrm{diag}\left(v\right)\right)=I$
and somehow use that to characterize $f(v)$.

Here is an answer for the special case in which $v_k = 1,\forall k\neq 1$. Let $B^{*}=\left(I-A\right)^{-1}$ and note that $f(\iota) = b_{11}^*$.The inequality can then be stated as
$$v_{1}b_{11}+\left(1-v_{1}\right)b_{11}^{2}\leq b_{11}^{*}.$$

Let us use the fact that $b_{ij}=m_{ij}/\Delta$ and $b_{ij}^{*}=m_{ij}^{*}$/$\Delta^{*}$,
where $M$ is the adjugate of $I-A\mathrm{diag}\left(v\right)$, $M^{*}$
is the adjugate of $I-A$ and $\Delta$ and $\Delta^{*}$ are the
respective determinants. The inequality is then
$$
v_{1}m_{11}/\Delta+\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}^{2}/\Delta^{2}\leq m_{11}^{*}/{\Delta^{*}}.
$$
Multiplying by $\Delta^{2}$ we get
$$
v_{1}m_{11}\Delta+\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}^{2}\leq\frac{m_{11}^{*}\Delta^{2}}{\Delta^{*}}.
$$

Recall that $M$ is the adjugate of $I-A\mathrm{diag}\left(v\right)$,
hence
$$ m_{11} = \det
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1-a_{22}v_{2} & -a_{23}v_{3} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}v_{K}\\
-a_{32}v_{2} & 1-a_{33}v_{3} & ... & ... & -a_{3K}v_{K}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
-a_{K2}v_{2} & -a_{K3}v_{3} & ... & ... & 1-a_{KK}v_{k}
\end{array}\right]
$$
and so $$m_{11} = \det 
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1-a_{22} & -a_{23} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}\\
-a_{32} & 1-a_{33} & ... & ... & -a_{3K}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
-a_{K2} & -a_{K3} & ... & ... & 1-a_{KK}
\end{array}\right]=m_{11}^{*}.$$
Since $m_{11}^{*}>0$
then our inequality becomes
$$
v_{1}\Delta+\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}\leq\frac{\Delta^{2}}{\Delta^{*}}
$$
Moreover, we know that
\begin{align*}
\Delta & =\left(1-a_{11}v_{1}\right)m_{11}-a_{12}v_{2}m_{21}...-a_{1K}v_{K}m_{K1}\\
 & =\left(1-a_{11}v_{1}-1+a_{11}\right)m_{11}^{*}+\left(1-a_{11}\right)m_{11}^{*}-a_{12}m_{21}...-a_{1K}m_{K1}\\
 & =\left(1-v_{1}\right)a_{11}m_{11}^{*}+\left(1-a_{11}\right)m_{11}^{*}-a_{12}m_{21}...-a_{1K}m_{K1}
\end{align*}
But
$$
I-A\mathrm{diag}(v)=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1-a_{11}v_{1} & -a_{12}v_{2} & -a_{13}v_{3} & ... & -a_{1K}v_{K}\\
-a_{21}v_{1} & 1-a_{22}v_{2} & -a_{23}v_{3} & ... & -a_{2K}v_{K}\\
-a_{31}v_{1} & -a_{32}v_{2} & 1-a_{33}v_{3} & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
-a_{K1}v_{1} & -a_{K2}v_{2} & -a_{K3}v_{3} & ... & 1-a_{KK}v_{k}
\end{array}\right]
$$
so
$$
m_{21}=-\det\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
-a_{21}v_{1} & -a_{23}v_{3} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}v_{K}\\
-a_{31}v_{1} & 1-a_{33}v_{3} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}v_{K}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
-a_{K1}v_{1} & -a_{K3}v_{3} & ... & ... & 1-a_{KK}v_{k}
\end{array}\right].
$$
In the case here with $v_{k}=1$ if $k\neq1$ we have
\begin{align*}
m_{21} & =-\det\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
-a_{21}v_{1} & -a_{23} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}\\
-a_{31}v_{1} & 1-a_{33} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
-a_{K1}v_{1} & -a_{K3} & ... & ... & 1-a_{KK}
\end{array}\right]\\
 & =-v_{1}\det\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
-a_{21} & -a_{23} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}\\
-a_{31} & 1-a_{33} & ... & ... & -a_{2K}\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
... & ... & ... & ... & ...\\
-a_{K1} & -a_{K3} & ... & ... & 1-a_{KK}
\end{array}\right]=v_{1}m_{21}^{*}
\end{align*}
and similarly
$
m_{k1}=v_{1}m_{k1}^{*},
$
and so plugging above we get
\begin{align*}
\Delta & =\left(1-v_{1}\right)a_{11}m_{11}^{*}+\left(1-a_{11}\right)m_{11}^{*}-v_{1}\sum_{k\ge2}a_{1k}m_{k1}^{*}\\
 & =\left(1-v_{1}\right)a_{11}m_{11}^{*}+\left(1-a_{11}\right)m_{11}^{*}-\sum_{k\ge2}a_{1k}m_{k1}^{*}+\left(1-v_{1}\right)\sum_{k\ge2}a_{1k}m_{k1}^{*}\\
 & =\left(1-v_{1}\right)\sum_{k\ge1}a_{1k}m_{k1}^{*}+\Delta^{*}\\
 & =\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi+\Delta^{*}
\end{align*}
where
$$
\Phi\equiv\sum_{k\ge1}a_{1k}m_{k1}^{*}.
$$
Plugging above then our inequality becomes
$$
v_{1}\Delta+\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}\leq\frac{\Delta^{2}}{\Delta^{*}}
$$
$$
v_{1}\left(\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi+\Delta^{*}\right)+\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}^{*}\leq\frac{\left(\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi+\Delta^{*}\right)^{2}}{\Delta^{*}}
$$
$$
\left(1-v_{1}\right)v_{1}\Phi+\Delta^{*}v_{1}+\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}^{*}\leq\frac{\left(1-v_{1}\right)^{2}\Phi^{2}+2\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi\Delta^{*}+\Delta^{*2}}{\Delta^{*}}
$$
$$
\left(1-v_{1}\right)v_{1}\Phi+\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}^{*}\leq\frac{\left(1-v_{1}\right)^{2}\Phi^{2}}{\Delta^{*}}+2\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi+\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Delta^{*}
$$
For $0\leq v_{1}<1$ this is equivalent to
$$
v_{1}\Phi+m_{11}^{*}\leq\frac{\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi^{2}}{\Delta^{*}}+2\Phi+\Delta^{*}
$$
or
$$
\left(\left(v_{1}-2\right)\Phi+m_{11}^{*}\right)\Delta^{*}\leq\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi^{2}+\left(\Delta^{*}\right)^{2}
$$
But
$$
\Delta^{*}=\left(1-a_{11}\right)m_{11}^{*}-\sum_{k\ge2}a_{1k}m_{k1}^{*}
$$
and
$$
\Phi\equiv\sum_{k\ge1}a_{1k}m_{k1}^{*}
$$
so
$$
\Delta^{*}=m_{11}^{*}-\Phi
$$
and hence our inequality is
$$
\left(\left(v_{1}-2\right)\Phi+m_{11}^{*}\right)\left(m_{11}^{*}-\Phi\right)\leq\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi^{2}+\left(m_{11}^{*}-\Phi\right)^{2}
$$
or
$$
\left(v_{1}-2\right)m_{11}^{*}\Phi+\left(m_{11}^{*}\right)^{2}-\left(v_{1}-2\right)\Phi^{2}-m_{11}^{*}\Phi\leq\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi^{2}+\left(m_{11}^{*}\right)^{2}-2m_{11}^{*}\Phi+\Phi^{2}
$$
or
$$
\left(v_{1}-1\right)m_{11}^{*}\Phi-\left(v_{1}-2\right)\Phi^{2}\leq\left(1-v_{1}\right)\Phi^{2}+\Phi^{2}
$$
or
$$
\left(v_{1}-1\right)m_{11}^{*}\Phi-v_{1}\Phi^{2}+2\Phi^{2}\leq2\Phi^{2}-v_{1}\Phi^{2}
$$
or
$$
-\left(1-v_{1}\right)m_{11}^{*}\Phi\leq0,
$$
which is true.

I imagine one can work this out in the case which $v_2$ can also be lower than one but $v_k = 1,\forall k \neq 1,2$, and from there try to come up with an induction argument to prove the general case.

Comment: how is there a simple case where $A$ is triangular?  Your first sentence says it is a positive matrix, hence irreducible.

Comment: @user8675309 I should have written nonnegative entries rather than positive entries. I corrected that in the question.

Comment: An obvious case is with $v=0$ (i.e., all entries of $v$ are equal to zero). In that case $f(0) = 1$, while $f(\iota) = b_{11} > 1,$ where the inequality follows because the matrix $(I-A)^{-1}$ will have diagonal entries higher than one, as can be seen from the Newman expansion.

Comment: @Andres The expression of $n=2$ looks complicated. Did you prove the case $n=2$?

Comment: @RiverLi I have not been able to show this for $n=2$ using algebra. Also, the function $f(v)$ is not monotonic. My only hope is that there is some property satisfied by that term $\sum_k (1-v_k) \frac{b_{1k} b_{k1}^2}{b_{11}}$.

Comment: Another option is to use Mathematica. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: The case with $v_2 = 1$ can be shown to hold using algebra.

Comment: The case with $v_2 = 0$ can also be shown to hold using algebra.

Comment: I have now shown the n=2 case. It's a lot of algebra.

Comment: @Andres Nice to hear that.

Comment: @RiverLi I imagine that one can try to prove the case n > 2 by induction.

Comment: Is this question still interesting for you?

Comment: This question is indirectly answered by this other question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388511/165163

Comment: @ClydeKertzer Indeed, this question is indirectly answered by [Inequality involving matrix inverse elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388511/264217). If you are interested, there is a more difficult version of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4537828/264217). We would appreciate any comments!